# Manhwa with a blonde female lead who has the power to see the future and a rich father with a very successful company

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's about this male lead that I don't remember much about, but I remember the female lead very well. She's blonde and has a father with a very successful company. She has the power to see the future or something like that. Her mother also had it. Her rich father used her mother's gift to be successful, but he abused her, and she died.

The protagonist becomes friends with the female lead and they develop a romance. He's older and I think he worked at the her father's company.

At some point, she runs away and starts living with the male lead. They ran away together because her father wanted her as a tool to maintain his wealth. I think he worked in some insignificant position at the company, and at some point he received another position, but related to FL.

I don't remember the characters' names. ML is tall, white with black hair. FL is white, blonde, short, and has light, blue or green eyes.

The story takes place in Korea and is a colored manwha

This was set in the modern world.

Comment: For example, what was his name? What was her name? Was this aimed at adults (with sex/nudity/gore) or more general audiences? What did her father's company do/make? What did she look like? Was this in colour or black-and-white? How did she see the future? What did it *look like* (e.g. on the page) when she was seeing the future? Was the future fixed in stone or could she change it? What was the protagonist's job? Why did they need to run away to be in a relationship? Was this set in Japan or another location? What did the cover art look like?

Answer (score 1):

This is *[The Jinx's Lover](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/jinx-yeon-in)*.

> The beautiful goddess of fortune hidden by a rich man came into the life of the poor and unlucky me.

The protagonist works for a friend, whose father is an extremely successful CEO. The CEO is extremely superstitious, but also seems to have extraordinary luck. This is a result of him having a woman confined as well as her daughter;

[image]

The woman was captured at some point by the CEO; she's some manner of supernatural creature that can bestow great luck to her "bound" person, but terrible luck if she touches anyone else. Both of them are hidden in the CEO's private apartment and barely interact with any humans. The mother is bound to the CEO; he also intends to bind her daughter to his son.

To the best of my knowledge, the daughter is not the CEO's daughter.

At some point, the daughter sneaks out and runs into the protagonist of the story, touching him for the first time, and thus binds to him instead of the CEO's son, but without him understanding the consequences. She is recaptured by the CEO and imprisoned again.

I didn't read much past this and my memory is a bit hazy, but the first chapter of the manhwa is a preview where the protagonist has perpetually terrible luck, at least until the girl discovers him again.